# Center two Elements (IMG with height based on container and second element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm in the process to create a Wordpress Template wheres on some point the user can add a list on the site with one picture.

- The height of the img should be proportional as tall as the list
- **So the img can't have a statement like {object-position: cover}**
- The img and the list should be centered

i've been struggling with this since days..

- I tried with img position absolute and height 100% but then the container doesn't center correctly because of the missing width of the img
- I tried with HTML table
- and basically everything that comes in my mind

I searched in the internet, but came up with no solution..

maybe i have to try to solving this Problem with javascript..

[my problem in a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUWNq.png)

Comment: Try it with JavaScript.. after the document loads, get the height of the container div and assign it to the image

Answer (score 0):

you can use **display:table** proprty of css to solve your issue. here is [demo](http://codepen.io/bherumehta/pen/oByvyK)

**CSS**

```
  .parent{
    display:table; /* make it table*/
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.parent > *{
  display:table-cell; /* make it table-cell*/
  height:100%;/* take max-height from both childs*/
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.parent > div img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.parent ul{
  padding:0;
  }
.parent li{
  padding:10px;
  color:#000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Image"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
     <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
    <li>List 6</li>
    <li>List 7</li>
    <li>List 8</li>
    <li>List 9</li>
    <li>List 10</li>
    <li>List 11</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```